# Assign node data to another variable jstree

Tags: javascript, jstree

I am trying to assign node data to a temporary variable within an context menu variable as

```
addToTable:{
                        // The "aggregate" menu item
                        label: "Show in table",
                        "seperator_before": false,
                        "seperator_after": true,
                        action: function(obj) {
                            tempNode = new Object();
                            tempNode.id =  node.id;
                            tempNode.original =  node.original;
                            //tempNode = jQuery_1_11('#ajax').jstree(true).get_node(node);
                            node.original.metadata.repeatme = true;
                            jQuery_1_11("#ajax").trigger("changed.jstree", {});
                             // or   jQuery_1_11("#ajax").trigger("changed.jstree", node);
                             // or   jQuery_1_11("#ajax").trigger("changed.jstree", tempNode );
                        }
                    },
```

after the trigger, if i use as follows

```
tempNode.original.metadata.sort_no = 2;
```

it also changes the "sort_no" attribute of original node.

I don't want original node data to be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you tried clone? https://api.jquery.com/clone/

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achive. Cant you just create a new variable to hold value for your `tempNode.original.metadata.sort_no` ?

Comment: if you call trigger on original node so change original node not tempNode

Comment: thanks @daremachine for your hint . clone only works on DOM elements. if you want to clone objects you need to use 

var newObject = jQuery.extend(true, {}, oldObject); 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object

Comment: I Think you need to rephrase your question. what do want to achieve with `Show in table`  ? do you want to call another function(). I think you can resolve your issue if you look at it from a different prospective

Answer (score 0):

It's because in Javascript you can [pass by value or reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Talk:JavaScript/Guide/Obsolete_Pages/Defining_Functions). So, with `tempNode.original =  node.original` you are assigning a reference to `node.original` rather than creating a new object. There is a whole other [discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object) on doing this but depending on which environment you are working on (Node, browsers, etc.) there are libraries available to help with this.